# cluster computing using starcluster and ipython on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, starcluster

I'm trying to experiment some with cluster computing on AWS. I'm completely new at this and having some issues. I'm trying to follow the tutorial found here: http://star.mit.edu/cluster/docs/latest/plugins/ipython.html#using-the-ipython-cluster. I use starcluster to start a cluster instance with the following:

```
starcluster start mycluster
```

Everything comes up as expected and it shows that the ipython plugin has loaded. I then try to execute the following command as shown in the tutorial:

```
starcluster sshmaster mycluster -u myuser
```

The connection fails, however, and tells me

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I am able to log in using

```
starcluster sshmaster mycluster
```

so I attempted to continue the tutorial logged in to the master but when I try to create the Client I receive and error:

```
AssertionError: Not a valid connection file or url: 
u'/root/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-client.json'
```

The only thing that I saw that seemed out of the ordinary is when the cluster was starting up this appeared:

```
>>> Running plugin ipcluster
>>> Writing IPython cluster config files
>>> Starting IPython cluster with 7 engines
>>> Waiting for JSON connector file... 
>>> Creating IPCluster cache directory: /Users/username/.starcluster/ipcluster
>>> Saving JSON connector file to '/Users/username/.starcluster/ipcluster/mycluster-us-east-1.json'
!!! ERROR - Error occurred while running plugin 'ipcluster':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/StarCluster-0.93.3-py2.7.egg/starcluster/cluster.py", line 1506, in run_plugin
    func(*args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/StarCluster-0.93.3-py2.7.egg/starcluster/plugins/ipcluster.py", line 276, in run
    plug.run(nodes, master, user, user_shell, volumes)
  File "<string>", line 2, in run
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/StarCluster-0.93.3-py2.7.egg/starcluster/utils.py", line 87, in wrap_f
    res = func(*arg, **kargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/StarCluster-0.93.3-py2.7.egg/starcluster/plugins/ipcluster.py", line 228, in run
    cfile = self._start_cluster(master, n, profile_dir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/StarCluster-0.93.3-py2.7.egg/starcluster/plugins/ipcluster.py", line 173, in _start_cluster
    master.ssh.get(json, local_json)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/StarCluster-0.93.3-py2.7.egg/starcluster/sshutils/__init__.py", line 431, in get
    self.scp.get(remotepaths, localpath, recursive=recursive)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/StarCluster-0.93.3-py2.7.egg/starcluster/sshutils/scp.py", line 141, in get
    self._recv_all()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/StarCluster-0.93.3-py2.7.egg/starcluster/sshutils/scp.py", line 242, in _recv_all
    msg = self.channel.recv(1024)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/ssh/channel.py", line 611, in recv
    raise socket.timeout()
timeout
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tutorial assumes `CLUSTER_USER = myuser` in `~/.starcluster/config` even though by default `CLUSTER_USER = sgeadmin`